# Запуск второго класса в новом окне. Python

Tags: python

Вопрос по сути простой, но как ни гуглил - ничего не нашел. Имеется два класса `class A()` и `class B()`
Необходимо сделать так, чтобы при запуске скрипта первым делом запускался `class A()`, а затем внутри него, уже в новом окне, вызывался `class B()`.

```
class A():
    def __init__(self):
        print('This is Class A')
        #Вот здесь необходим запуск класса B в новом окне
        #В данный момент он вызывается в текущем
        B()

class B():
    def __init__(self):
        print('This is Class B')

A()
```

**Сейчас я имею:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Требуемый результат:**

Запущено с помощью двух файлов.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11712629/13970074

Comment: Класс не запускается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нельзя один раз запустить скрипт в двух разных окнах.

Можно либо один скрипт запустить два раза, либо иметь два разных скрипта и каждый запустить отдельно.

При этом в любом случае это будут два разных процесса, и они не смогут просто так взаимодействовать. Вам придётся отдельно прописывать логику взаимодействия - например, через сокеты.

Answer (score 1):

я думаю можно сделать так:

```
class A():
    def __init__(self):
        print('This is Class A')
        input(Для продолжения нажмите любую клавишу . . .)
        #Вот здесь необходим запуск класса B в новом окне
        #В данный момент он вызывается в текущем
        B()
        input("Для продолжения нажмите любую клавишу . . .")

class B():
    def __init__(self):
        print('This is Class B')

A()
```

Также если вам больше не нужно сообщение "This is Class A", можно сделать так:

```
import os

class A():
    def __init__(self):
        print('This is Class A')
        input("Для продолжения нажмите любую клавишу . . .")
        os.system("cls") # Очищаем консоль
        #Вот здесь необходим запуск класса B в новом окне
        #В данный момент он вызывается в текущем
        B()
        input("Для продолжения нажмите любую клавишу . . .")

class B():
    def __init__(self):
        print('This is Class B')

A()
```

Надеюсь я вас правильно понял

Comment: не запускается + вряд ли это создаст второе окно с консолью

Comment: тут суть в том, что после нажатия какой-либо клавиши и очистки консоли, класс А завершается и запускается класс Б. Мне же нужно сделать так, чтобы они работали одновременно, но как я понял, сделать этого невозможно, так что я лучше просто создам класс Б в отдельном скрипте

Comment: Ну, как вам сказать. Во-первых, я вас просто не правильно понял. А во-вторых, все возможно, просто нужно найти не очивидное на первый взгляд решения решение. Сори если вас это не устраивает, но я просто по такому принципу живу: )

Comment: Подождите, вам нужно чтобы они одновременно работали? Для этого существуют потоки из модуля Theard.

Comment: Не знаю можно ли это назвать одновременной работой, но как минимум я думаю класс А будет работать тогда же когда и класс Б